# what do +0100 +0200 mean in linux command `stat` results

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, stat

I use stat to get information of files, I notice

```
Modify: 2011-03-02 14:23:33.489430232 +0100

Modify: 2012-11-15 10:13:26.534178635 +0200
```

what do `+0100` `+0200` mean?

Comment: It's the timezone the preceding time is expressed in... i.e. UTC+1

Comment: @Tyson: avoid posting an answer in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This mean *time offset from UTC*

This could vary between summer time and winter time:

```
env TZ=Europe/Paris LANG=C date +"%F %T.%N %z" 
2015-12-07 09:28:18.664129444 +0100
```

Because, we are now using winter time, but

```
env TZ=Europe/Paris LANG=C date +"%F %T.%N %z" -d '2015-08-01'
2015-08-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0200
```